# Babylonjs Subtracting Cylinder From Mesh Solid

Tags: typescript, babylonjs, csg

I've put together a simple test using CSG in Babylon.  I am trying to subtract the cylinder "hole" from the "upright" panel that I have created.  However, It's not working properly.  I feel that I am missing something.

Here's my playground
https://playground.babylonjs.com/#4489EV

Answer (score 1):

I'm also inexperienced in Babylon.js but I could get it to work as follows:

- The meshes you create (e.g. hole) are automatically added to the scene and you don't want that;
- Use [hole|Upright].setEnabled(false) to prevent showing them in the scene;
- After you compute your CSG object, you then call .toMesh() so that the CSG mesh is displayed;
- Note that if you use subtract, it returns a new CSG, maybe you rather want subtractInPlace.